# General error : 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: database, backup, laravel-5

I'm trying to backup from my **Laravel** application using **Spatie package** but when running **backup:run** commend I get this error:

```
Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I solve this on localhost and production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you follow all of the setup instructions?

In your `config/database.php` file, edit the mysql database config and add:

`'dump_command_path' =>' '` // absolute path to where mysqldump lives on your system
That path is probably this, or something very similar:  `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`

Answer (score 5):

In your config/database.php file, edit the mysql database config and add:

```
'dump' => [
               'dump_binary_path' => 'C:/xampp/mysql/bin/', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
               'use_single_transaction',
               'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
            ],
```

Answer (score 2):

in database.php

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'dump' => [
               'dump_binary_path' => 'C:/xampp/mysql/bin/', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
               'use_single_transaction',
               'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
            ],
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

and your .env should be

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:mNx544BUIAeVZ7MWN4UcmK1SroMY+OXzxHmu2u7KEkc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

one more thing if you did not configure your mail then disable mail service in backup.php othervise you will get error this solution worked for me

Comment: no works? it works for you? no windows compatibility